# Lenovo Phab 2 Tango Error Extracting Image

Tags: android, google-project-tango

I was previously developing for the Tango Tablet Dev Kit and was able to extract and image from the image buffer with no problem. Now, however, with the same code, but on the Lenovo Phab 2, this is the image that is produced: [image]

So, I am wondering, what has changed in the Tango API, or hardware native to cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specifics of the images are a bit different between the Yosemite tablet and that Phab2:

Fisheye:
Yosemite: (width: 640, height: 480, stride: 768)
Phab2 Pro: (width: 640, height: 480, stride: 640)

Color camera:
Yosemite: (width: 1080, height: 720, stride: 1080)
Phab2 Pro: (width: 1920, height: 1080, stride: 1920)

Make sure you are properly reading, and handling, these values from the TangoImageBuffer and you will be in good shape.